# How to display hexadecimals in a readable way in java

Tags: java, android, udp, hex, byte

I have a device sending me their IP address in hexadecimal form through a udp packet.
I want to print out that IP address in the form that it came in. FF FF FF FF for example.

But I'm not sure how to do that, and my code won't work because it just turns everything into the unreadable UTF-8 symbol.

```
byte[] ipAddr = {(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF};
String ipString = new String(ipAddr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

How can I change the code so that printing ipString gives "FF FF FF FF"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: The sample code fails because the data is not UTF-8, yet you claim (in the string constructor) that it is UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ByteBuffer` to convert the 4 bytes to an `int`, then use `String.format()` to format that in hexadecimals with leading zeroes, like this:

```java
byte[] ipAddr = {(byte)0xFC, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xFF};

int ipInt = ByteBuffer.wrap(ipAddr).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
String ipString = String.format("%08x", ipInt).toUpperCase();

System.out.println(ipString);
```

*Output*

```
FCFDFEFF
```